# Random src value within javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of my `javascript` code here. I would like `lbox.src` taking a random value from a a list of websites I will give it. Could someone help me ???

```
var lbox = document.createElement('iframe');

lbox.src = 'http://www.websites.com';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the sites into an array:

```
var sites = [
"http://www.websites.com",
"http://www.websites2.com",
"http://www.websites3.com"
];
```

and then just select a random one from there:

```
lbox.src= sites[Math.floor(Math.random()*sites.length)];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myWebsites = ["http://www.test1.com", "http://www.test2.com", "http://www.test3.com"]

var website = myWebsites[Math.floor(Math.random()*myWebsites.length)]
```

Regards,

Max